# Why does axis2 1.6.2 java2wdsl.sh ignore class members of complex type

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl, apache-axis

Let's say I have a ClassA which contains some members of type String and 1 member of an array of ClassB which in turn contains just a String member. Something like this:

```
public class ClassB{

    private String string1;
    public ClassB(){
        string1 = "value1";
    }
}

public class ClassA{

    private String string1;
    private String string2;
    private ClassB[] classB = null;

    public ClassA(){
        string1 = "value1";
        string2 = "value2";
        classB = new ClassB[2];
        classB[0] = new ClassB();
        classB[1] = new ClassB();
    }
}
```

Now I define a member function in my end point class as follows:

```
//...
public ClassA getClassA(){
    return new ClassA();
}
//...
```

This code is obviously useless and incomplete and probably even wrong as I wrote it out of my head, but it demonstrates my point.

When I run java2wsdl.sh on this class (or a similar construct) I get a .wsdl file but the array ClassB[] is ignored.
I understand that axis2 by default uses JAXB serialization and I tried to control the output  using annotations but to no avail.

How can I change the behaviour so that ClassB[] is included in the .wsdl file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A necessary (but maybe not sufficient) condition to make this work is to declare ClassB as static.

Comment: That is not acceptable unfortunately. I need many instances of ClassA, each with their own array of ClassB's. Why would a static ClassB work BTW? The presented case is general enough that one would expect that Axis2 would be able to cope with it I would say. I can of course edit the generated .wsdl myself, but that would brake my automatic build system.

Comment: Note that my suggestion is not to declare the classB attribute static, but to make ClassB a static inner class. The reason non static inner classes are not supported is that they have implicit references to instances of their outer classes and there is no general way to map that kind of relationship to XML.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. After posting this question I have already found out that creating contract-last Web Services is a can of worms because WSDL is limited to what can be expressed in XML and WSDL does cannot (and should not) know implementation specific data types. I have decided to edit the .wsdl file to my liking and use it as the basis for a contract first approach. I also decided to drop Axis2 and use Apache CXF. I also looked at Spring WS, but I think contract-first CXF is the best option for my requirements.